# How can I import a private-key to Blockchain.info in order to use it?

Tags: blockchain.info, import

I recently bought a BTC-wallet from my friend. It has a cold storage wallet ("Watch only") and a private key (which is a bunch of numbers and letters). How can I use it in Blockchain.info? How do I make (confirm?) transactions with it?

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE. Your question was not clear as it was originally stated, so I edited assuming that you are trying to import the private key to Blockchain.info. Please check whether the question is still aligned to your issue and edit it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

you question is not clear, what exactly have you bought?

anyhow if you have the private key you can import them in blockchain.info wallet in the Import/Export section. but if you bought it from someone else he/she also has the private key and so the ability to spend the bitcoins.